# SEOMATIC v1.1.45 install

Tags: plugins, upgrades, plugin-seomatic

Finally making progress into a production environment (**Pro license installed**) and I see that the SEOMATIC has an update - 1.1.45 - I followed the [instructions](https://github.com/nystudio107/seomatic/blob/master/DOCS.md#installation) but am lost, as SEOMATIC is already installed in my instance of Craft; instructions want me to install it...is there a step I am missing to get this update complete?

Please let me know what I am I missing here -- thank you a ton! =)

**Edit @10:00 03/29/2017**

Thank you everyone for your answers! =)

If I am reading all the comments/answers correctly, I should do the following:
`rm -R /var/www/html/craft/plugins/seomatic`
`cp -rv /home/psa/Zips/seomatic /var/www/html/craft/plugins`
`service apache2 restart`

Is that correct? Thanks again for the assistance here!

Answer (score 5):

To update plugins like SeoMatic, just download the latest (either clicking on the direct download link from the /admin/updates/ page in your admin area or from github).

Then you just then need to upload the new folder, overwriting the old one, to your server in the /craft/plugins directory (make sure you rename the download to seomatic as before, removing the '-master' that github adds).

Comment: Just to clarify, while Craft CMS itself has a one-click update system, applying core Craft updates automatically, plugins require a few extra manual steps to update. As J. Baptiste mentions above, an improved approach is coming with Craft 3, due to launch later this year.

Comment: While commenting on your own answer is cool @alexr, don't be shy editing if you're adding something substantive!

Comment: Should really add that you should reload any admin page after this, to trigger any schema migrations that need to be done...otherwise the site will error out from the front end

Comment: Also - you should really empty the old plugin folder first, otherwise you might have no longer files left hanging around, which can cause issues.  So delete old plugin files, upload news ones into same folder, load an admin page.

Comment: Hello and thank you!! I should do the following:  
`rm -R /var/www/html/craft/plugins/seomatic`    
`cp -rv /home/psa/Zips/seomatic /var/www/html/craft/plugins`    
`service apache2 restart`

Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

Craft is going to have a better update system in a version 3. With Seomatic you can also be able to update via composer. As far as I know.